# Skeletonize fails to create vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: python, scikit-image

I want to skeletonize an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4tB1.jpg) with the function `skeletonize` from `skimage.morphology` but the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFZkn.png) is really disappointing. Meaning it fails to recognize the horizontal and vertical lines connecting the different instruments of the drawing.

Any tips? What can I improve?

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import filters
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize

# read image
img = cv.imread('realpars_p_id_diag_mod.png',0)

binary = img > filters.threshold_triangle(img)
    
# true false to one
binary_cp = binary.copy()
binary_cp[binary_cp == True] = 1
binary_cp[binary_cp == False] = 0

# skeletonize image
skeleton = skeletonize(binary_cp)

# print images
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(skeleton,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('skeleton Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.savefig("binary and bin_skeleton.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `np.unique(binary)`?

Comment: What does `binary` look like before you pass it to `skeletonize`?

Comment: What is the purpose of `binary_cp`? It isn't used anywhere.

Comment: ```binary``` is an array with values 0 for False and 1 for True .

Comment: ```binary_cp``` gets feeded to the function ```skeletonize```, I just corrected it, still the same output.

Comment: Can you show `binary_cp`?

Comment: ```np.unique``` can also be omitted. Was to check unique values. But is redundant.

Comment: Can you post your original image, 'realpars_p_id_diag_mod.png'? The link to the input image is a .jpg, which probably contains compression artifacts that will affect the result...

Answer (score 1):

That *is* disappointing!  But there's clues in the curvature of the lines, and the fact that the diagonals go in the opposite direction as they do in the original image: you are skeletonizing the wrong image! You want to skeletonize the *black* parts, not the white parts, which means you need to *invert* the binary image. Or, more simply, change the sign in the threshold expression. Here's my updated code:

```py
from skimage import io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import filters
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize

# read image
img = io.imread('/Users/jni/Downloads/P4tB1.jpg')[..., 0]

# Note: we want the black bits to be True, so use <
binary = img < filters.threshold_triangle(img)

# skeletonize image
skeleton = skeletonize(binary)

# print images
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax[0].set_title('original')
ax[0].set_axis_off()

# note the reversed colormap, gray_r
ax[1].imshow(skeleton, cmap='gray_r')
ax[1].set_title('skeleton (inverse)')
ax[1].set_axis_off()

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: plot result]